# Webpack configuration in express

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I have a newbie question. I am reading this [tutorial](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/building-a-simple-crud-app-with-react-redux-part-1/#table-of-contents):

The `app.use` part use webpack with express. i.e. webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware. My question is that can I put these 2 configurations into `webpack.config.js`, rather then put them in server.js. If I can put them back to webpack.config.js, why do I put them here?

In server.js

```
const port = 3000;  
const app = express();  
const compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {  
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpack config file is where you configure settings to specify:

- how webpack bundles your code
- what plugins it makes available in code
- what preprocessors it uses to process your static assets
- define entry and output points

What it does not do is specify how your framework (Express) will use some plugins. In the [blog](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/building-a-simple-crud-app-with-react-redux-part-1/#table-of-contents) you have linked, the config file includes this part:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
],
```

Here, you are specifying that the `webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin` will be **available** in your application for use. It doesn't specify **how** it will be used. Moreover, note that `webpack-dev-middleware` hasn't been included in config.

You need to tell Express specifically that the framework is supposed to use the `webpack-dev-middleware`, that's why you need to write `app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')..` in the `server.js` file. Similarly for `webpack-hot-middleware`.